# Drawing a sphere with quads

Tags: stage3d

I need to draw a large sphere composed of small quads. I am very new to Stage3D so I need some advices. How can I create a sphere with hundreds (maybe thousands) of quads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with Stage3D, but I do know that moosefetcher is wrong. It is entirely possible to create spheres out of quads. Here is a modelling tips video, in it you can see there is a sphere made entirely out of quads.

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-X1eevWU9s)

Because I haven't worked with Stage3D I don't know anything about it. Though I'm sure you could look at tutorials for creating quad spheres in 3DSMAX, Maya and Cinema 4D. The steps should be very roughly similar.

However, if they are not similar. I'm pretty sure you can download a model of a quad sphere and load it up in Stage3D and then examine it and try to replicate it. Heres a link to download one:

[download](http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/quads-sphere-3ds-free/730832)

It's not avaliabe in Stage3D, so I did a bit of research and theres a few programs that allow you to convert .blend files to stage 3d files and .obj files to stage 3d files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cover the entire surface of a sphere using just quads. At least SOME triangles will be required.